# How can I make text visible when found with browser search?

Tags: html, css

I have in a web-page repeated `div`s which are normally transparent, but are made opaque when the mouse hovers over their parent:

```html
<div class="entry">
  ...
  <div class="info">
    some information text
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
div.info {
    opacity: 0;
}
.entry:hover div.info {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I would now like to make that page searchable through the standard browser "find in page" functionality. That actually works, but if the found text is within such a `div.info`, it is obviously invisible, too.

Is there a way I can make my `div` visible not just on hover, but also if it contains found text? Or specify the style of found text, including that is is supposed to be visible?

I looked at the other [CSS pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), but none of them match my purpose. I also experimented with the pseudo-element `::target-text` as an alternative to found text.

Do I have to do this via JavaScript?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think you can do that. You can detect the ^F keypress event, but you can't detect what the user is searching with it. As far as I know, the only way to do this is to make your own searching feature.

Comment: @JongwooLee, thanks! There also doesn't seem to be a way to style the found text, is there?

Comment: @ADonda No. JavaScript (and CSS) can’t access the search box. The search box isn’t part of the DOM, it just displays on top of the page. And there isn’t any pseudo class to apply custom CSS to this, either.

Comment: I don't mean the search box, but the text found in the page. In Chrome it is highlighted with an orange background. Is this styling something that can be modified?

Comment: @ADonda Sorry for being confusing. And yes, you can't modify this style (as far as I know)